# How stop click event on CHtmlView drived class?

Tags: html, mfc, sdi

In SDI application on right pain view on a FormView I am showing HTML preview using ChtmlView Navigate function. When I open doc/docx file in HTML preview then it was editable. I want to prevent click event so no one can edit this.

How can I stop click event on `CHtmlView` drived class ?

I try

```
BOOL CHtmlPreview::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
if(pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN || pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONUP || pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
{pMsg->message =    0;pMsg->wParam  =   0;  pMsg->lParam  = 0;}
}
```

But when I click on previewed file (doc/docx ) in Chtmlview container then it is not handle by `CHtmlPreview::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)` and not its parent `CFormView` drived class `PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)`. Control not goes to these function.

My problem is like:
 
[CHtmlView class and focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544398/chtmlview-class-and-focus)

I also try to overrides `CHtmlView::OnTranslateAccelerator` but this is not available in my `CHtmlPreview` class whose base class is ChtmlView.

Thanks

Comment: Your HTML view control is created in edit mode, I am not sure how. Are you sure this is not derived from `CHtmlEditCtrl` or another class? Check if there is an override for `_OnNavigateComplete2` or if there is any class to `SetDesignMode(TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks for Reply. In SDI right pane divided in two row in second row(0,1) I am using Dialog whose class inherited from a CFormView on that I am creating Htmlview Create(NULL,NULL,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_BORDER, theApp.pRect,theApp.DlgWnd,ID_HTMLVIEW)   Here theApp.DlgWnd is Dialog inherited from CFormView. My CHtmlPreview class inherited from ChtmlView class and there is no override function _OnNavigateComplete2 and no class set to SetDesignMode(TRUE).